# How to create a partial search in Meteor that only returns permitted data

Tags: search, meteor

I'm trying to create a search feature in Meteor 1.8.1 that does the following:

- returns partial matches, e.g. "fish" will find "fish", "fishcake" and "dogfish"
- has server-side control of which documents are returned, so search results don't include documents that are not published to the user
- is reasonably efficient
- returns a limited number of results

This seems like it should be a common requirement, but I'm failing to find any solution.

[MongoDB full text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) will only return on whole words, so will only find "fish".

[Easy search](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) doesn't support server-side permissions, as far as I can tell.

I could try a regex solution but I think it would be expensive?

Thank you for any solutions!

Edit: From discussion it seems that Easy Search does support server-side filtering using a selector, and this would be the best solution. However, I can't get a selector working from the examples and documentation. For clarity, I've created a [new question for that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59560457/how-to-implement-a-selector-in-easy-search-for-meteor)

Comment: The regular expression is the way to achieve what you want, but efficiency won't be a feature, as it will be doing a brute force search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation explicitly states that for advanced use cases you may want to use elastic search and offers you a [pluggable extension](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/tree/master/packages/easysearch_elasticsearch) to ease the burden of integration.

https://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/recipes/#advanced-search

> You might wish that a search for cafe returns documents with the text café in them (special character). Or that your search string is split up by whitespace and those terms used to search across multiple fields.
>
> You should consider using a search engine like ElasticSearch for your search if you have these usecases. ElasticSearch allows you to configure precisely how your fields are being searched. One way you can do that is by analyzing your data, so that searching itself is as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how changing the search engine will alter how I can control the data sent from the server?

Comment: You're looking for a performant alternative to a mongo regex query so outsourcing this functionality to elastic search would alleviate your problem.

Comment: It is a core requirement that search only returns documents the user has permission to see, and that does not appear to be supported by Easy Search, regardless of which engine you use. Please say if I am wrong and there is a way to do this!

Comment: Why are you assuming that using elastic search would negate your ability to limit returned data??! You can customize your configuration to limit the results!

https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/352
https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/441

Comment: https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/420

```

UsersIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
    collection: Meteor.users,
    fields: ['username', 'profile.firstName', 'profile.lastName', 'emails.0.address'],
    engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB(),
    permission(options) {
        return options.userId; // only allow searching when the user is logged in
    }
});

```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately if I copy the code from the doc https://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/recipes/ I still see all search results in the client when the user is not logged in. The selector does not do anything. I must be missing something but cannot figure out how to make selectors function.

Comment: I've edited the question with example code showing how I've tried to use a selector but can't get it to work.

Comment: Would kindly create a small repo with a fixture sample of your DB so we can debug things better?

Comment: Thank you, I've added a repo to my question.

Comment: Couple of things need to be addressed first. The question is confusing, asking about proper way to form a partial search but in reality we want to apply filtering to the search. Second, the example you provided is misleading; those code snippets are not the ones in the repo. Aside from the fact that the repo is not proper! there's no such thing as an owner property on those lists documents to filter with!!

Comment: I'd advise you to reedit the question. Now onto the problem, please clone this repo [here](https://github.com/matteodem/easy-search-leaderboard). You shall find that he's applying filtering with categories and it's working fine.

Comment: Hi - the owner property is created when you make a list private, see step 5.

Comment: I can't see what is different between my code (taken from the docs) and the leaderboard example...what is the magic step I'm missing to make the selector work?

Comment: No there's. 
```
PlayersIndex.getComponentMethods()
   .addProps('categoryFilter', $(e.target).val())
  ;
```

Comment: That adds a filter term from the client side. It doesn't seem to explain why the selector in my repo doesn't get called at all? However, I take your point that the question has changed and I'll make a new one about the selector issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've finally got some traction on this; the documentation seems to have an error, which is why everything I tried didn't work!

Comment: If you post an answer saying to use Easy Search with MongoDBEngine, and referencing the Leaderboard example for selectors, I will accept it. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I appreciate the gesture, but I guess you editing the answer with the new question is sufficient.